# Этимология слова "яд"

Tags: этимология

В греческом языке **токсин** означает **яд**; там понятно, откуда корни.
Слово **токсикон** относилось к стрельбе из лука, а стреляли стрелами, смазанными отравляющим веществом, которое впоследствии и приобрело это название.
Интересно, а откуда взялось слово **яд** в русском языке?

Answer (score 3):

Значение "яд как отрава" отмечено уже в др.-рус. языке. Изменение значения  "яд как пища" (пища - плохая пища - отравленная пища - отрава) могло произойти в условиях эмоциональной речи. Корень "яд" в исходном значении сохранился в словах "всеядный и ясли" (старшее значение - еда).

Аналогичное явление можно наблюдать для слов "трава и травить, отравить, отрава". Изначальное значение для  "трава" - это то, что тратится, съедается, то есть нечто съедобное.

Comment: Похоже, вы правы:"яд" близок "еде", и это действительно отчётливо видно по словам всеядный, а так же "яства". Но "ясли"?

Comment: Ясли - это изначально "кормушка для скота", сравнить: есть - ясли, гудеть - гусли.

Comment: Ещё значение "еды" встречается в видовых биологических названиях "паук-птицеяд" (в просторечии "птицеед") и "орёл-змееяд".

Comment: А интересно, не родня ли яд словам ядрёный и ядро?

Comment: Я тоже пытался думать на эту тему (съедобная часть ореха?), но подтверждений не нашёл. Разве что у Фасмера упоминается исходный для некот. слав. языков вариант слова *ědro, смутно напоминающий о "еде".

Comment: У Шанского ядро - от о.-с. en/dro, где en - это "в, внутри", dr/ tr - суффикс, поэтому ядро - внутренняя часть чего-то, сердцевина. Родственное слово -  утроба.

Comment: А ядрёный? По семантике от яда недалеко.

Comment: Ядро - ядреный. 1. Имеющий полное, созревшее ядро (об орехе).2. Выдержанный, крепкий, созревший, отличный, наилучшего качества (переносное значение).

Comment: Про орех не знаю, но вот ядрёный - через чур насыщенный - употребляется часто. Например: ядрёный самогон, ядрёная пища( когда много перца). Здесь к ядру нет никакого отношения, ближе к ядовитому. Ведь когда есть перенасыщенность, вещество может стать ядом. Тот же алкоголь.

Comment: @Alex_ander ядро совершенно точно из ПИЕ ***e̯endhrom*** "то, что внутри".